# parse xml file and store data in database

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

```
import MySQLdb
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.dom.minidom

xmldoc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("Country.xml")

country= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("country")[0]

sensors = country.getElementsByTagName("sensor")

for sensor in sensors:
    Translation = sensor.getElementsByTagName("Translation")[0].firstChild.data
    Name = sensor.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].firstChild.data
    Prefix = sensor.getElementsByTagName("Prefix")[0].firstChild.data
    Percentage = sensor.getElementsByTagName("Percentage")[0].firstChild.data
    Position = sensor.getElementsByTagName("Position")[0].firstChild.data

    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","akshay","country")

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Drop table if it already exist using execute() method.
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS country_table")

# Create table as per requirement
sql = """CREATE TABLE country_table (_
         Translation  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         Name  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         Prefix INT(5) NOT NULL,  
         Percentage INT(3) NOT NULL,
         Position INT(3) NOT NULL
          )"""

sql1= ("INSERT INTO country_table(Translation, Name, Prefix, Percentage,Position) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s,%s)"
   %(Translation, Name, Prefix, Percentage,Position))

try:
   # Execute the SQL command

     cursor.execute(sql1)

except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 5, in
>   
>       xmldoc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("Country.xml")   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py",
>   line 1918, in parse
>       return expatbuilder.parse(file)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py",
>   line 924, in parse
>       result = builder.parseFile(fp)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py",
>   line 211, in parseFile
>       parser.Parse("", True) xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 43, column 0

Please help.

Comment: Could you post the XML file ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/af5MP.png

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed Origination and Transaction tags , just close them and it should work just fine.